# Python: Generate String Combinations with set count of type. (String of x length with, x numbers, x uppercase, x lowercase)

Tags: python, string, passwords, combinations, python-itertools

Looking for most efficient way to generate string combinations with qualifiers,

A string of length 16, with 2 numbers, 8 lowercase, 6 uppercase, a way to iterate over all combinations.

Perhaps using itertools.filterfalse or itertools.dropwhile?

Comment: Apologies, edited question.

Comment: Take a look at Riccardo Bucco current answer, it should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, permutations, product
from string import ascii_digits, ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations

def generator():
    n_gen = combinations_with_replacement(ascii_digits, 2)
    l_gen = combinations_with_replacement(ascii_lowercase, 8)
    u_gen = combinations_with_replacement(ascii_uppercase, 6)
    for numbers, lowercase, uppercase in product(n_gen, l_gen, u_gen):
        for p in multiset_permutations(numbers + lowercase + uppercase):
            yield ''.join(p)
```

Example (print 100 strings):

```
g = generator()
i = 0

for s in g:
    if i > 100:
        break
    print(s)
    i += 1
```

Of course you should not print them all, there are too many!! Indeed there are more than 10^26 possible strings! Do NOT create a list with them unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: note: combinations is without replacement, so you will never generate a string with more than 1 `a`. but using replacement makes plain permutations not work well, because it will yield some permutations more than once.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 True! Thanks for your contribution! Do you know any workaround?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using `combinations_with_replacement` and then a `set` to avoid duplicate permutations, which will have a significant memory footprint

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Yes that's definitely not possible... Ok I'll try to think at something else

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I updated my answer. i used `combinations_with_replacement` as you suggested and `multiset_permutations` from sympy package (it allows to generate permutations without doubles).

Comment: Awesome! someone should suggest adding such a function to `itertools` as well :P

Answer (score 1):

Check the Source code online [here](https://pynative.com/online-python-code-editor-to-execute-python-code/)

```
import random
import string

def get_random_alphanumeric_string(length):
    letters_and_digits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    result_str = ''.join((random.choice(letters_and_digits) for i in range(length)))
    print("Random alphanumeric String is:", result_str)

get_random_alphanumeric_string(8)
get_random_alphanumeric_string(8)
```